# Send mail via cronjob/php, RHEL

Tags: php, email, redhat, cron

I am trying to send an e-mail by a cronjob using a php script.
The script itself works fine when executed in a shell.
When it is run by cron, the attachment is missing.

OS is RHEL 7

Cron entry :

```
30 4 1 * * user /usr/bin/php /path/sendmail.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The user in crontab is the same as shell user

The script :

```
<?php 
require '/usr/share/php/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$msg = "";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host       = "mail.domain.com"; 
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
  'ssl' => array(
  'verify_peer' => false,
  'verify_peer_name' => false,
  'allow_self_signed' => true
  )
);
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
$mail->do_debug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->Port       = 25;                    
$mail->Username   = "SMTP-User"; 
$mail->Password   = 'SMTP-pass';        
$mail->setFrom('from@domain.com', '');
$mail->addAddress('receiver@domain.com', '');
$mail->Subject = 'Domains';
$mail->Body = 'Attachment : domain2.csv';
// Attach the uploaded file
$mail->addAttachment("domain2.csv", 'domain2.csv');
if (!$mail->send()) {
$msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
$msg .= "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Not too complicated.

Can anyone tell me, how to fix this ?
I think it is again one of these SELinux settings problems.

TIA
Wayne

Comment: If the the problem is SELinux related as you think, then [check YOUR logs](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-02c04b0b030dd3c3d58bb7acbbcff033505dd3af) since, well, we cannot do that for you.... But also consider that your attachments simply can’t be located because you omit a directory path. - But rather than guessing, try your job without discarding the error messages and it can probably tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Ouch, of course it was the path to the attachment. Sometimes I am too blind to see my own mistakes. Thanks a lot HBruijn.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute path than the relative path as the cron runs from a different context

```
$mail->addAttachment(dirname(__FILE__)."/domain2.csv", 'domain2.csv');
```